# MS Teams Localization for developer websiteUrl and privacyUrl

Tags: microsoft-teams, manifest

I'm trying to find a way to localize developer privacyUrl and websiteUrl. [Teams docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/apps-localization) seems to not provide informations about that.

I'm using the following json for my localization file but Teams tell me that it is incorrect:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.8/MicrosoftTeams.Localization.schema.json",
  "name.short": "My App Test",
  "developer.websiteUrl": "http://myapptest.com",
  "developer.privacyUrl": "http://myapptest.com",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's because website/privacy URLs are not localizable as of now.

Answer (score 0):

The schema doesn't support localized versions of these, but you can do whatever you want on those pages - they are just web pages. They could do locale detection and show localized content, just like any other webpage on the internet.